# Incorrent model passed to Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

This might be a duplicate question but I can't for the life of me know what the solution is. I'm trying to load a partial view with a table based on the ID of a clicked link.

I'm getting this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MasigasigTrackingSystem.Models.Invoice]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'MasigasigTrackingSystem.Pages.Masigasig.MainPage.TripTicket.TripTicketListModel'.'

I can't seem to figure out how should I passed the model to the partial view.

Here is what my OnGet looks like:

```
     public IList<Invoice> Invoice { get; set; }

    public PartialViewResult OnGetDetails(int TripTicketID)
    {
        var invoices = from m in _context.Invoice
                       select m;

        invoices = invoices.Where(x => x.TripTicketID == TripTicketID);

        Invoice = invoices.ToList();

        return Partial("_TripTicketListDetails", Invoice);
    }
```

Here is my partial view:

```
@model TripTicketListModel
<h1>Hello, test</h1>
<table id="TripEntryList" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Invoice[0].InvoiceNumber)
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Invoice)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceNumber)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Partial View Required `TripTicketListModel` and you are passing the model `Invoice`. It means you are passing wrong model.

From your `View` code i can say your `Invoice` is used inside `TripTicketListModel`, so try below solution.

```
 public PartialViewResult OnGetDetails(int TripTicketID)
 {
        var invoices = from m in _context.Invoice select m;

        invoices = invoices.Where(x => x.TripTicketID == TripTicketID);

        TripTicketListModel model = new TripTicketListModel();
        model.Invoice = invoices.ToList();

        return Partial("_TripTicketListDetails", model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, just another question, I have a user id in my invoice table but I want to connect it to my users table so that when passed into the partial view it will show the name instead of the ID. How do I try to do that?

Comment: for that you need to add name property in your invoice model and when your are getting value of invoice list, that time you need to find the value of name from the id and need to add it in your invoice list.